# Is my solution to this puzzle wrong or a transposition of the official one?

Tags: analysis, puzzles

I saw the following puzzle recently in a newspaper:

> ### Black to play and win
>
> ```
> 6rk/6qp/2Bp4/P1pP1p2/3bnP2/6BQ/7P/5R1K w - - 0 1
> ```

My proposed solution was

```
1. ...   Nf2+
```

and the lines I foresaw were

```
2. Bxf2  Bxf2
3. Rxf2  Qg1 mate

2. Bxf2  Bxf2
3. (something else)  Qg1+
4. Rxg1  Rxg1 mate

2. Rxf2  Bxf2
3. Bxf2  Qa1+ and interposing B or Q only delays the end
```

However, the given solution was

> ```
> 1. ...   Bf2!
> 2. Rxf2  ...
> ```
>
> (If `2. Bxf2?  Nxf2+  3. Rxf2   Qg1 mate`)
>
> ```
> 2. ...   Nxf2+
> 3. Bxf2  Qa1+ and white resigns
> ```

I can see three possibilities:

1. I missed something
2. My solution is as good as the official one
3. They're actually equivalent under transposition

Which is the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're not *equivalent*, but your solution is just as good. In fact, it's more easy to find because Nf2+ is a 'forcing' move.

Answer (score 2):

They aren't quite equivalent because of the differences in the position if White declines or partially declines the sacrifice (for example, after Nf2+ Rxf2 Bxf2, White doesn't have to retake the bishop - but after Bf2 Rxf2 Nf2+ declining the knight instantly loses the queen.)  But both should win, even if Bf2 is slightly better.